# How to index a mat with 2 cols from another Mat...?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have a namelist (text-matrix) `nl43` and multiple indexes into it (in `gr43`) and would like to assign the elements index by the 4th and 5th columnn of `gr43` to 2 variables, `A` and `B`.
When accessing a single column, this would be `nl43[gr43[;Column];]`, but my fingers just refused to copy & paste that statement to do the 2nd assignment, because my instinct suggested that there must be an easier way ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found `(A B)←⊂[1 3]nl43[gr43[;4 5;]` and am sadly disappointed by myself, as it never occured to me to re-think this bit before. Now that I answered that question myself, I assume there's not much room for refinement???

Hmm, there is a nested way to do this: `(A B)←(⊂nl43){⍺[gr43[;⍵];]}¨4 5`
I hesitated to even look at it, because it felt too "clumsy". But performancewise it is a clear winner: .234 secs vs. .64 !!

Comments? ;-)

Comment: I originally wanted to post this as a real question (after that suggestion from my instinct...). But then I thought some RTFM would help and it did. However, the process might be interesting, and since self-answers are excplicitely encouraged, I thought it might be a nice way to get some action for the APL-tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an analogue to something like

```
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[3 3 reshape 3 1 20 18 1 20 6 1 20] // []A instead of abcde... in Dyalog
cat
rat
fat
  // result is a matrix
```

I would intuitively expect a nested argument to indexing to also work.

```
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[(3 1 20) (18 1 20) (6 1 20)]
 cat  rat  fat
  // result is a vector of vectors
```

Alas, this is not, or not yet, been implemented.  I have used a similar dfn approach to indexing in the past but never on anything but a vector.  Interesting how this kind of extended indexing could work on matrices and higher-dimensional arrays.

Comment: That could be done with squad-indexing (introduced in Dyalog 14, IIRC): `(⊂3 1 20)(⊂18 1 20)(⊂6 1 20)⌷¨⊂'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: Would there be a nice Squad-indexing solution to the Sudoku problem where you have a 9 x 9 matrix and want to split it into a 3 x 3 matrix of 3 x 3 matrices?

i.e. `SudokuMat[ (1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9) ; (1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9) ]`

Comment: Hmm, "nice squad" is a challenging one, I have no idea atm, I'm sorry. I'd do `↑(⊂1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0)⊂[1]¨1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0⊂SudokuMat` `⍝  ⎕ML=1`